# Map an entity with another entity that is associated with another two lookup entities using JPA

Tags: java, jpa

I have below table design to be followed.
TABLE_A, TABLE_B - Lookup Tables. Columns - ID, NAME, STATUS, CREATE_DATE, UPDATE_DATE
TABLE_C - ID, NUMBER, NAME, ...Other Attributes
TABLE_D - ID, ID_A, ID_B, ID_C
TABLE_E - ID, ID_A, ID_B (this is available in DB but not used)
This table have IDs from Table A, B and C.

Associations:

TABLE_C to TABLE_D: 1:n
TABLE_A to TABLE_D: 1:n
TABLE_B to TABLE_D: 1:n
TABLE_E to TABLE_A: n:1
TABLE_E to TABLE_B: n:1

Initially, TABLE_C can have only 1:1 association with TABLE_A and TABLE_D doesn't have ID_A, instead TABLE_C have ID_A.

JPA Entity Created for TABLE_C
@Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
@JoinTable(name = "TABLE_B", joinColumns = {
@JoinColumn(name = "ID_C", referencedColumnName = "ID") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
@JoinColumn(name = "ID_B", referencedColumnName = "ID") })
private Set<TABLE_B> valueForD;

While inserting/updating entries to TABLE_D were done like this.
SAVE METHOD:

EntityC obj = new EntityC();
obj.setValueForD(repository.findAllById(inputparam.getIds(),EntityB.class));

Now adding ID_A to the TABLE_D totally disrupted the JPA Enitity and the SAVE METHOD,
We cannot find how to write JoinTable after adding ID from A to TableD, also the association changed from 1:1 to 1:n.
We cannot put separate table to map ID_C to ID_A.
As ID_A can have multiple ID_B selected for one ID_C.
We have to track which ID_Bs are selected for which ID_A for an entity C.

Note:
As we had 1:1 for TABLE_A to TABLE_C intially we only maintained TABLE_C to TABLE_B mapping.
But now as it is changing we can no longer follow this.

we tried saving TABLE_D after TABLE_C.
But this is not maintaining the JPA Entity and somewhere the data is getting erased.
Following issues of a product:
create - moved to status 2. (SAVE TABLE_C and put ID_C, ID_A, ID_B to TABLE_D)
Edit - moved to status 1 again. (SAVE TABLE_C and put ID_C, ID_A, ID_B to TABLE_D)
Edit - move to status 2.(now TABLE_D is getting deleted for the particular ID_C)

Need to know how to make the PersistentSet for the TABLE_D(having ID_A, ID_B (from two non-associated lookup tables) and ID_C ) in TABLE_C.
Shall we use TABLE_E.